# How to off the Bootstrap Loading Button while text is still Empty

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap-3

Please help
I want to off the bootstrap loading button while my textbox is still empty
the user need to fill all textbox before the submit button will change the text to loading

whats happening to me is that when the user click the submit button the bootstrap is loading too even the page textbox still has a required field.

this my current code

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.3/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.3/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css">
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.3/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">  
$(function() { 
$(".btn").click(function(){
    $(this).button('loading').delay(1000).queue(function() {
        $(this).button('reset');
        $(this).dequeue();
    });        
});
});   
</script>

<form class="form-horizontal" action="button.php" method="post" style=" width:450px;">

    <label class="control-label col-xs-3">Username Name :</label>
    <input type="textbox" class="form-control" name="txtfirst" placeholder="First Name"required>

    <label class="control-label col-xs-3">Password :</label>
    <input type="textbox" class="form-control" name="txtlast" placeholder="Last Name"required>

    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" data-loading-text="    Loading...    ">Login</button>
</form>
```

Please help

Answer (score 2):

From the code it looks like your js function call is bound to click event of the button and not submit event of the form. The click event does not do any form validations.

Try this: http://jsfiddle.net/Dde4U/

```
$(function() { 
    $(".btn").click(function(){
        if($('.form-horizontal').valid()){ //Checks if form is valid
            $(this).button('loading').delay(1000).queue(function() {
                $(this).button('reset');
                $(this).dequeue();
            });      
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: I applied your code and i fill up the textboxes. the page is submitting but what i need is to change the "Login" to "Loading" while the page is submitting or loading.

Comment: There is negligible time between click and submit to observe that.

Comment: I applied it to my other form data entry in my resume' form. Because it takes time to save all info from CV thats why i want to put loading in the button. i just create username and password as a sample.